# domain mapping confused about sunrise

Tags: multisite, domain, wp-config

When i try to access my domain mapping page it asks me to move the line define('sunrise', 'on') above the last require_once line in the wp-config file. It is already above this line. I tried moving it higher and even to the top of the file(below the opening

I recognizes if i remove the line alltogether (asks me to uncomment the line or add it if it is missing) so I know It is not looking at some other file. What could cause this behavior?

http://pastebin.com/wTWhxPjj

Comment: Just a quick guess - it's not already defined to not 'on' somewhere else?

Comment: *@lathomas64* please post your config file (**without your database connection info!!!**) to a [pastebin](http://wordpress.pastebin.com/) so we can double check.

Comment: at work right now but afterwards I'll be sure to

Comment: Of what is that `$base = '/';` left over?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparantly this happens with the newer version of domain mapping because sunrise.php itself needs to be updated. To solve it I:

Copy the new sunrise.php file from wp-content/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/sunrise.php to wp-content/sunrise.php and you'll be fine.

And it works now.

Comment: Fantastic!  I'm deleting my incorrect answer and hoping more people upvote yours.  Make sure to mark it as the correct answer once you can.